# Get SVN warn about not adding specific files

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

At work, when I am ready to commit my files, sometimes I forget to add newly created files which breaks the build and everybody starts yelling at me (well, not really but it *is* embarrassing!). We are using tortoise SVN (although I have no problem using svn via the command prompt if that may be involved in the solution).

My question is, can I get SVN (or Tortoise SVN) to warn me that I am *NOT* committing some *.h/*.cpp files. My current workaround is to sort the list, but considering the size of repository and the sheer amount of unversioned files, I would like for SVN to point it out to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add unversioned files to ignore list. Then everything else should be files You want to commit.

TortoiseSVN also displays unversioned files in commit window, so if ignore would not work try to create changelists: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html

---

So the only option I think is to add files while working on them (creating them). Svn add should work for you. You can use "check for modifications" window to add them. At the same time You can add them to changelist so You can acces them quickly later while commiting.

Sory, but or you or your software should know what to commit. If you have that much unversioned files only You can tell SVN what is important.

Another option that can help You is to use RegExp in ignore files names, if You can remove from commit window some of this files it should be easier for you to find important files that You want to commit.

Comment: That is the first thing I tried. Problem is, some files with the same extension are versioned which disallows ignoring the same extension. For example, mesh `*.obj` files are versioned, but visual studio `*.obj` files I'd like to ignore, but that does not work. And that is the biggest problem I see currently in my list. There are a ton of `*.obj` files generated by Visual Studio and I cannot add them to the ignore list.

Comment: Any chance to meve them into different directories?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are too many and as SVN cannot link deleted/added files I don't think my superiors would agree.

Answer (score -1):

If you commit on the base directory, Tortoise will recognize modified and new files in a list which you can then pick and choose from.

Comment: I think this is the problem: it just lists them without selecting them, making them _very, very_ easy to miss.